# Mental fatigue and recovery schedule

Tags: performance

(Complete novice here)

I am looking for some research or publications that would tackle the question of how much rest is required for good mental performance / productivity and is there a schedule that would describe the relationship of work and rest.

The problem i am trying to solve is that of optimal productivity from a one knowledge worker (e.g. me) who’s output isn’t related directly to hours worked (not call center where every minute online talking to customer equals productivity). 
Empirically (observing self and colleagues) I know that working long hours every day leads to worsening productivity, but how many hours can be worked without a productivity dip? What if we measure productivity over a period of a week - is working 12 hours mon-wed and then 6 thu and fri better than working 7 hours daily?
What about need for long break - a vacation, there seems to be a negatively accumulating coefficient.

Any clues to research appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1480 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16047

Comment: @ChrisRogers 2nd link certainly is useful, 1st - not so much :)

Comment: Related: [Jar principle](https://theaspergian.com/2018/09/26/the-jar-principle-on-over-stimulation-social-exhaustion/)